# Find all the values of $x \in \mathbb R$ from an equation

Tags: calculus

Find all the values of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ from this inequality:

$$\left|\frac3{x^3-8}\right|=\left|\frac1{x-2}\right|$$

This is my work:

$$\frac{\left|\frac3{x^3-8}\right|}{\left|\frac1{x-2}\right|}=1$$
$$\left|\frac{3(x-2)}{x^3-8}\right|=1$$
$$\left|\frac {x-2}{x^3-2^3}\right|=\frac13$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left|\;\frac3{x^3-8}\;\right|=\left|\;\frac1{x-2}\;\right|\iff3|x-2|=|x-2||x^2+2x+4|$$

Now, it obviously *has* to be $\,x\ne 2\,$ , so...

Comment: So you mean that i will have in the end: |x2+2x+4|=3,right? And what sould I do further on?

Comment: @marinaaaa, observe that $\;x^2+2x+4>0\;$ **always** . Why? Just check this parabola opens upwards and its discriminant is negative! So in fact you have $$x^2+2x+4=3\implies (x+1)^2=0\;\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$x^3-8=x^3-2^3=(x-2)\{x^2+2x+2^2\}=(x-2)\{(x+1)^2+3\}$

So assuming $x-2\ne0,$ we can safely cancel $x-2$  and utilize $|x^2+2x+4|=x^2+2x+4$

Comment: So you mean that i will have in the end: |x2+2x+4|=3,right? And what sould I do further on?

Comment: @marinaaaa, you have $x^2+2x+4=3$ straight away

Answer (score 0):

$$\left|\;\frac3{x^3-8}\;\right|=\left|\;\frac1{x-2}\;\right|\iff3|x-2|=|x-2||x^2+2x+4|$$

Since $x-2\ne0$ we can cancel both sides and get a quadratic  $|x^2+2x+4|$ which has no solution in the real axis.

Comment: So you mean that i will have in the end: |x2+2x+4|=3,right? And what sould I do further on?

Comment: @Simar, did you notice your answer is an almost exact copy of mine but more than 4 hours later...? In fact, all the mathematical line in your answer is *exactly* the same.